# Create inheritance users from base asp.net identity user or implement different interfaces for each role?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I've got two types of users, both have the same properties but each one will be able to do specific operations. Can I have the same class for both type of users and implement different interfaces for each role or should I use inheritance instead ?
For example: class User implements IBuyer and ISeller.

Comment: You need to think about how the different user subtypes can be _correctly_ mapped to database tables by EF (if you're using EF, which has its own limitations). Are you instead intending to use your own user-store code with ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you want to use ASP.NET Identity in the first place? You don't need to use it - and if you have a substantially different data-model for users than ASP.NET Identity's then you should consider just doing it yourself otherwise you'll have to spend hours fighting ASP.NET Identity's design, which won't end well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you could but, why wouldn't you have two different user classes? Like, class Buyer implement IBuyer and class Seller implement ISeller, I think that would make your code clearer. You could also add a class User with the basic properties they both share, even if they are all of them as you said, which implements an interface called IUser with the shared methods it could have and then your classes Buyer and Seller could inhered from User and have their own separated and independent methods. Anyway, yes, what you commented is possible as well.